# Setcookie не работает  на запись с солью

Tags: php, cookie, kohana, sha1

Есть код, который добавляет соль к печеньке:

```
$agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) : 'unknown';
return hash_hmac('sha1', $agent.$name.$value.Cookie::$salt, Cookie::$salt);
```

На выходе получается:

```
string(163) "e1067287c0666935ec52946bd486240fcbefb013~a:2:{i:102750;a:4:{s:5:"count";s:1:"1";s:4:"cost";s:4:"2750";s:6:"modify";a:0:{}s:5:"group";s:2:"10";}s:4:"test";s:1:"1";}"
```

Такую конструкцию никак не получается установить через setcookie.

Стоит убрать соль, в примере выше это 'e1067287c0666935ec52946bd486240fcbefb013' - и все чудесным образом записывается, все ОК.

Стоит вместо json отправить строку без кавычек '"' - все ОК.

Никак не могу уловить связь, почему так. В ограничение на количество данных в печеньках не упираемся.

Kohana 3.3.3.1

В чем может быть причина и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записал вашу строку в куки и вывел посредством кохановской Cookie::set/get

`e1067287c0666935ec52946bd486240fcbefb013~a:2:{i:102750;a:4:{s:5:"count";s:1:"1";s:4:"cost";s:4:"2750";s:6:"modify";a:0:{}s:5:"group";s:2:"10";}s:4:"test";s:1:"1";}`

с солью и без неё все отработало ровно, судя по всему проблема где-то ещё